# Position Cell Content Outside of Table

Tags: html, css

I have been attempting to get the content of a `td` to be visible outside of its parent `table` element.  I am not even sure that it is possible but I thought I'd ask here before giving up.

What I am looking to do is to "prepend" a table row with an icon but I would like for it to display next to the table, not inside of it.

I have tried applying absolute positioning to the container of the icon which is a `div` inside of the `td` with negative margins but that pulls the icon under the edge of the table.

The generated table row looks something like this:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <div class="icon-container">  // I want this to display
      <i class="icon"></i>        // to the left of the row
    </div>                        // outside of the table
    Cell content here
  </td>
  ...
</tr>
```

Comment: Can you use :before on TD elements? If yes, it could work. Something like td.special:before

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless I severely misinterpret what you're after, this is trivial. If the icon is always in the leftmost td of each row, you can do this with a relative position on the icon-container. Just move it to the left by the width of the icon plus the size of the table's border, and a bit of padding for good measure.

```css
.icon-container {
    position:relative;
    left:-17px;
    height:0; overflow:visible;
}
.icon-container .icon {
    display:block; width:10px; height:10px;
    background-color:green; border-radius:5px;
}
```

That's all. Relative positioning won't affect the other elements surrounding it, so you won't have to do anything else.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/ANM7k/).

Comment: I can't believe I forgot you can just set the container's height to zero. That makes my answer look so silly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think positioning works well or at all on tables/rows/cells. Here's what I did [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aLtZB/). Since I wanted the container to be on the outside, I wrapped it in yet another container. I set the outer container to relative position and the inner container to absolute positioning. I can then give the inner container whatever left/top I want. The outer container must have a width and height of 0 otherwise the cell content will get pushed around.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class = "icon-super-container">
                <div class = "icon-container">
                    <i class = "icon"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            Cell content here
        </td>
        <td>More cell stuff</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class = "icon-super-container">
                <div class = "icon-container">
                    <i class = "icon"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            Cell content here
        </td>
        <td>More cell stuff</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

c

```
table {
    margin-left:100px;
    margin-top:50px;
    border:1px solid blue;
    padding:15px;

}

td {
    border:1px solid black;
}

.icon-super-container {
    position:relative;
}

.icon-container {
    background-color:red;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    position:absolute;
    left:-15px;
    top:2px;
}
```